# Bundle ID Mac AppStore and non Mac AppStore

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

I'm releasing my Mac app both on the Mac AppStore and from my Online Store. I'm wondering if I should have the same bundle id for both or a different one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing bad in the same bundle ids. Sandboxed apps and non-sandboxed are linked to a different paths. If you sign your online store app with Developer ID (which is definitely worth of) and use sandboxing in both distributions - there will be almost no difference.

Comment: What does "linked to a different paths" mean?

Comment: `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` will return a sanboxed container path. For non-sandboxed it will be in a different directory path.